# Error while loading ASP page with activex COM components

Tags: com, asp-classic

We have deployed one classic ASP web application to our web server (Windows 2000 advanced server with SP4) say server Y.

We have COM components on the same server which we create from DLL's build on some other machine. For eg. we build DLL's on machine X and then copy these DLL's to server Y and build COM components refering to those DLL's on server Y.

Now if we run the application URL from machine X - say URL would be "http://(server Y)/app.asp" It just worked fine with loading of all relative activex components; BUT if we run the URL from any other machine we receive error as "ActiveX component can't create object".

kindly suggest!

Thanks,
Ravin

Answer (score 2):

Just copying your COM components .dlls doesn't work. You need to register the COM component on all machines you want them to run on.

Run

```
regsvr32 C:\<full path>\<your component>.dll
```

on your machine Y to register the COM component.